# How Can I convert byte array to String in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a json as below. I need to convert the image to a `byte array` and post it as a `String`.

I can convert the image to `byte array` but how can I convert it to `String`?
I am getting an error while converting `byte array` to `String`.

**Error:**

```
"not a valid UTF-8 sequence"
```

**JSON:**

```
"photo1": "[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73, ..... ,]"
```

**Image Data to Byte Array:**

```
func getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData:NSData) -> Array<UInt8> {

    // the number of elements:
    let count = imageData.length / MemoryLayout<Int8>.size

    // create array of appropriate length:
    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: count)

    // copy bytes into array
    imageData.getBytes(&bytes, length:count * MemoryLayout<Int8>.size)

    var byteArray:Array = Array<UInt8>()

    for i in 0 ..< count {
      byteArray.append(bytes[i])
    }
    
    return byteArray
}
```

**Using getArrayOfBytesFromImage Function:**

```
if let string = String(bytes: getArrayOfBytesFromImage(imageData: imageData), encoding: .utf8) {
        print(string)
    } else {
        print("not a valid UTF-8 sequence")
    }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: "not a valid UTF-8 sequence" 
here the else block always works.

Comment: Hang on, is the JSON that you showed the desired result?

Comment: json there is an example.
It shows the value I will send as an example.

I looked at what type of value to send json using https://app.quicktype.io/ website.


I need to send this array as string.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not UTF-8 bytes, so don't say `encoding: .utf8`. Those bytes do not form a string, so you should not use `String.init(bytes:encoding:)`. You should get the value of those bytes, and get their `description` one way or another (e.g. by string interpolation).

You don't even need a byte array here. Just go straight to strings, since that's what you're after.

```
let imageData = Data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) // for example
let string = "[\(imageData.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ","))]"
print(string) // prints [1,2,3,4,5]
```